# XMLUnit ignoring version diffrences in links

Tags: xmlunit

I want to ignore similar urls with diffrent version or parameters.Is there a way to achieve that using XMLUnit?

**Control XML:**`<script src="https://test.com/test.js?param=12345" type="text/javascript"/>`

**Test XML:**`<script src="https://test.com/test.js?param=123" type="text/javascript"/>`

I want to ignore such diffrences while generating all diffrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell XMLUnit to use a `DifferenceEvaluator` that you provide yourself.

With this evaluator you'd return the original outcome unless it is an `ATTR_VALUE` comparison and you can identify it is the `src` attribute on a `script` element (look at the `Comparison`'s control target and its parent) - in which case you return `SIMIALR` or even `EQUAL`.

Comment: Thank you.Is there any way to ignore these kind of order changes
*Control node*
`<script>
line 1
line 2
</script>`
*Test node*
`<script>
line 2
line 1
</script>`

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize your question here. You mean you have nested text in your script and you want to ignore the order of lines? That's pretty unusual and not supported by default, you can certainly do that yourself inside the `DifferenceEvaluator` for text content differences.